# MPI_Barrier not working fproperly

Tags: c

In mpi.h , I am trying to use MPI_Barrier, but it's not working fine.
Here's an example:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    int i,j,rank,np;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&np);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    for(i=0;i<np;i++)
    {
        if(rank==i)
        {
            printf("\n(%d)\n",rank);
            for(j=0;j<5;j++)
            {
                printf("%d\t",j);
                if((j%10)==0)
                    printf("\n");
            }
        }
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
(0)
0   

(1)
0   

(2)
0   

(3)
0   
1       2       3       4       1       2       3       4       1       2       3       4
1       2       3       4
```

(executed with 4 processors)
So all processors start printing values at the same time, even if there is a barrier.
Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf` to `stdout` is buffered, and by default flushes the buffer at each `\n`. So each processor in turn prints its rank and flushes the buffer with `\n`, then prints 0 and flushes the buffer. Each processor then uses `printf` to load "1 2 3 4" into the output buffer, but doesn't flush. The flush happens the the end of the program, so all the final lines appear at once.

To see your IO in order, add `fflush(stdout)` before the barrier. For total control over I/O ordering, dedicate one processor to performing I/O, as MPI doesn't provide any I/O ordering guarantee.